# Поиск корня функции методом дихотомии

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, численные-методы

Выполняю задание курсовой работы по Численным Методам и Моделированию на ЭВМ: найти корень функции и отобразить на графике функции методами итераций, дихотомии и Ньютона. Для данного задания (и дисциплины в целом) я выбрал язык Python через простоту выполнения подобного рода заданий. 
Функция:

```py
def f(x):
    return np.exp(x)-np.log(x)-20
```

С методом итераций я справился: он находит корень, проходя по массиву NumPy, и отображает найденную точку на графике matplotlib, построенному по вышеупомянутому массиву:

```py
def Iteration(a,b):
    args = np.arange(a,b,0.0004)
    root = 0
    i = 1
    while i < np.size(args):
        if(f(args[i-1])*f(args[i]) < 0):
            root = args[i-1]
            break
        i=i+1
    print(f"Корінь функції згідно методу ітерацій знаходиться у точці x = {root}")
    plot(args,root)
```

А вот с методом дихотомии ситуацию несколько иная: он находит корень с заданной точностью, однако найденную таким способом точку программа отображать отказывается:

```py
def Dyhotomy(a,b):
    args=np.arange(a,b,0.0004)
    root = 0
    while abs(f(b)-f(a)) > 0.0004:
        mid = (a+b)/2
        if f(mid) == 0:
            root = mid
        elif (f(a) * f(mid)) < 0:
            b = mid
        else: a = mid
    root = (a+b)/2
    print(f"Корінь функції згідно методу дихотомії знаходиться у точці x = {root}")
    plot(args, root)
```

Собственно, проблему я уже нашел: она состоит в том, что значение, находимое с помощью данного метода попросту отсутствует в массиве f(args), по которому строится график, и потому маска точки не работает. Сама функция plot(args,root) выглядит так:

```py
def plot(args, root):
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,5)) #Створення нової фігури з заданим розміром

    # Візуальне налаштування
    plt.title("Завдання 1: ")
    plt.xlabel(r"$x$, Аргумент") #Підпис осі  x
    plt.ylabel(r"$Y(x)$, Функція") #Підпис осі y

    plt.plot(args, f(args), label='Function')

    Root_mask = f(args) == f(root)
    plt.scatter(args, f(args)[Root_mask], label = 'Корінь функції', color='black', marker='x')

    plt.legend(loc = 'upper center') #Розташування легенди графіку
    plt.grid() #Відображення сітки

    plt.show()
```

Нужно переделать, как я понял, либо саму функцию поиска, так, чтобы она искала значения только в массиве, либо функцию построения графика. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, курсач близко. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используй Root_mask. Просто находи значение по нужному методу, записывай его в переменную и используй последнюю для того, чтобы нарисовать точку. В твоем случае это аргумент root, что передается в функцию постройки графика:

plt.scatter(root, f(root), label = 'Корінь функції', color='black', marker='x')